# href doesn't work in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, href

Can please someone tell me why my HREF's aren't working in IE. They work in chrome, but not IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

   <title>Steves Homepage</title>

    <style>

#left {

    float:left;
    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    width:33%;

;

}

#right {

    float:right;

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    width:33%;

}

#middle {

    float:left;
    width:33%;
}

#wrapper {

    width:100%;

}

li {

    list-style-type: none;

}

          </style>

    </head>


    <body>



<div id="wrapper">


    <div id="left">


        <ul>


            <li><b>Useful Docs</b></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Passwords.txt">Passwords</a>
</li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Server Naming Convention.txt">Server Naming Convention</a></li>

            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Numbers.txt">Numbers</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/GPO.txt">GPO</a></li>

            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Useful Emails.txt">Useful Emails</a></li>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Spreadsheets</b>
            <li><a href="file://///birmingham-nas/nsd/Engineering/Official_Structure/DSL_details/EMEA_DSL_Details.xls">IP Spreadsheet</li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="middle">

        <ul>

            <li><b>Configurations</b></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/MRV Config/MRV Config.txt">MRV Config</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/MRV Config/MRV Lines.txt">MRV Lines</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/DMVPN Config.txt">DMVPN Config</a>
</li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="right">

        <ul>

            <li><b>How To Guides</b>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Meeting Rooms.txt">Meeting Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Activations/Masergy Activations.txt">Activations</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Engineer Dispatch Guide.txt">Engineer Dispatch Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Temperature Issues.txt">Temperature Issues</a></li>
            <p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>test</p>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

So when I click on the links, absolutely nothing happens. However in Chrome this works just fine. Also My spacing doesn't work. So I'm trying to make 3 columns, left middle and right. This displays perfectly in chome, but not IE. So that you can understand the layout, it looks like this img below currently. As you can see, the MRV configs etc should be under the Configurations section. But they are skewed off to the right hand column for some reason.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwMoF.png

Comment: have you tried prepending file:// before the C:\ addresses? Also, any spaces may need to be converted to %20

Answer (score 0):

your URL is just malformed so make it like this

```
<a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Temperature Issues.txt">Temperature Issues</a>
```

absolute links for local resources must be like this

```
 file:///c:/your/great/folder
```

Comment: Hi,

Yeah I tried that way also. I will try it again now and get back to you

Comment: So yeah, I've just replaced that line with the following 
            <li><a href="file:///c:/Users/stegar06/Desktop/Useful Stuff/Temperature Issues.txt">Temperature Issues</a></li> I pressed ctrl +f5 to refresh the home page. Still nothing. The wierd thing is, you see my network share line (in the line with the words birmingham-nas) this link actually works. Everything else doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The "links" you are using in your href attributes are Windows specific file paths. They will hardly work from a webpage, they will only work on Your computer.

But if that is your intension, then you can observe in Chrome while hovering a link, that it extends the beginning with:

file:///

That is the correct format.

For the CSS part in IE:

don't just use min and max widths becouse IE has some trouble finding out what you want. Try giving simply width: 33%; for your three divs.

Best wishes!

Comment: Hi,

Please see my code again. I have modified it to use the file:/// method. I still have no success.